# timeUnit=microseconds to milliseconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parquet

I am using this command- `timestamps=pd.to_datetime(table[0], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')` and in schema `timeUnit` is displayed as microseconds.

```
timeWithOffset (Timestamp(isAdjustedToUTC=false, timeUnit=microseconds, is_from_converted_type=false, force_set_converted_type=false));
```

and `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S%f %p'` gives no issues but still `timeUnit=microseconds`.
How can I change timeUnit to milliseconds?

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks for the reply.Tried it, still not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the code you used when you "tried it".

Comment: Sorry, you should be *dividing* by 1000, not multiplying. Duh.

Comment: @MattDMo I used this-"timestamps.microsecond/1000" still gives the same output and when I used "timestamps.timestamp() %1000" this gives ('DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'timestamp' ) error.